# Error while launching flutter Application

Tags: flutter, gradle

I am new to flutter development so i followed the google getting started with flutter page as is.

When i used the andriod studio (or) visual studio to create a demo flutter application and try to run it on a emulator i get the below lines .

*Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\personalnicknacks\softwares\flutter\hello_app_world\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\ing12703.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1*

I have the tried following things.
1)Ensured my JAVA_HOME environment is correct pointing.
2)used the latest java version 16.0
3)used the andriod studio to install the flutter plugins.
4)have also tried to install the gradel manually using the page https://gradle.org/install/#manually
5)now even my gradel output is correct
C:\Users\ing12703>gradle -v

Welcome to Gradle 7.0.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- File system watching enabled by default
- Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
- Native support for Apple Silicon processors
- Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/release-notes.html

---

### Gradle 7.0.2

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 16.0.1+9-24)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

The suggestion I got online was to downgrade the JDK to say a 12 or so but is that the only viable option or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

OK another thing i did try now was to indeed delete JAVA SDK 16 and install the JAVA SDK 15 and it works like a charm.

However I still wonder how do we know when to upgrade to latest JAVA SDK? is some compatibility list of SDK and their respective versions available in flutter documentation?